# Spinwait for a number of spins in Portable Class Library

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, portable-class-library, .net-core

I'm looking to replace the SpinWait method in a PCL targeting ASPNET Core, .NET 4.5.2, and Android+iOS via Xamarin but can't find a direct equivalent. At the moment I'm looking at replacing

```
System.Threading.Thread.SpinWait(10);
```

with

```
SpinWait spinWait = new SpinWait();
SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => spinWait.Count >= 10);
```

but I have no idea if I'm opening a can of worms by doing. or if maybe

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) SpinOnce();
```

is better. I had avoided this because SpinOnce() yields after every spin so seems likely to be less efficient.

**Context:**

I'm currently porting this high-precision timer to a PCL (ASPNET Core, .NET 4.5.2, and Android+iOS via Xamarin) and coming up against an issue with the SpinWait method removal.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/98346/Microsecond-and-Millisecond-NET-Timer

In the .NET Framework proper there is a method SpinWait() which accepts an int which dictates how many spins to wait for 
(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.spinwait(v=vs.110).aspx) but the System.Threading.Thread namespace isn't available when targeting this combination of frameworks but does include a SpinWait struct (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.spinwait(v=vs.110).aspx) which gives me access to SpinOnce() and a SpinUntil() method which accepts a boolean-returning function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out my intuition about avoiding yielding was not entirely correct and have discovered that in the source of SpinUntil (http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/SpinWait.cs) there is actually a repeated call to SpinOnce().

Without the error checking logic it looks like this:

```
//Error Checking Logic
SpinWait spinner = new SpinWait();
        while (!condition())
        {
            //Timeout checks
            spinner.SpinOnce();
            //Timeout and Yielding checks
            }
        }
//Return Logic
```

I am therefore taking this as an acceptable example of implementation and will be using (unless a better solution presents itself) something similar to the below to recreate the desired behaviour.

```
SpinWait spinner = new SpinWait();
    while (spinner.Count<10)
    {
        spinner.SpinOnce();
        //Timeout and Yielding checks
        }
    }
```